# Howto access someone's offline WordPress website (localhost)?

Tags: wordpress, localhost

a friend of mine has offline WordPress website and he wants me to check it out and fix some bugs before he put it live. I've never worked with offline websites before, so I'm not familiar with the way I can access it. 
Is there any way he can grant me access to it even though  we are not on the same network?

Comment: Define offline? Is it posted on a webserver? Does he have it on GIT? Does he have it on his PC?

Comment: no. take backup with database and send to your friend. he will set up backup website in your computer

Comment: @ImAtWar It is on his PC

Comment: @Shital Marakana Can you please be more specific? How do I do that?

Comment: You can take a look at this site: https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/

Comment: @Yamu thank you! I'll check it out.

Comment: copy your website folder. and export your database. then paste to another server and import database. then only change url by using this tool. download below tool and past in website folder. you can change url by using below tool.

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: @Shital Marakana Thank you very much!